# Why does the Swift compiler mark errors pessimistically?

Tags: xcode, swift

I find that Swift is quick to mark down changes i make as compiler errors in the side panel, and then when i compile, it decides i am right after all. Is Swift just pessimistic about my code?

Can I get the compiler to wait for me to finish the line before declaring it wrong?

Comment: I use Shift-Command-B (shortcut for `Analyse`) instead of building.  It helps to clear such errors away.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing pessimistic. Xcode uses the same tool - the compiler - to get the errors. However, it usually compiles only one file, using cached compiled objects for the other files. It also doesn't invoke the compiler after every change in your code, so errors that are already fixed can stay there in the side panel.

Building the project fully forces Xcode to refresh the cache and get the current list of errors from the compiler. I do agree that Xcode has many imperfections and this is one of them. When you can't find an error, just rebuild the project.

Note that IDEs for other languages often rebuild the project automatically to solve such problems. This is currently not an option in Swift because it would take too much time.

Comment: Objective C compilation isnt like this though.

Comment: @angelofcode I am actually seeing exactly the same issues with Obj-C compilation. However, the languages differ. Swift is not very good with incremental compilation yet.